# AngularJS: store/load html+directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I have a single page app with two routes. Each route loads html code with big amount of angular directives from back-end. After html is loaded I have to compile directives so AngularJS allows to work with them. But the amount is so big that [this](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js) solution hangs browser for a minute, so I used promises to compile directives sequentially with:

```
var functions = [];
angular.forEach(angular.element("ang-accordion"), function (value, key) {
         functions.push(function () {
               var taskDeferred = $q.defer();
               $compile(value)($scope);
               $timeout(function () {
                      taskDeferred.resolve();
               }, 1);
               return taskDeferred.promise;
         });
});

function serial(tasks) {
        var prevPromise;
        angular.forEach(tasks, function (task) {
            //First task
            if (!prevPromise) {
                prevPromise = task();
            } else {
                prevPromise = prevPromise.then(task);
            }
        });
        return prevPromise;
    }
serial(functions);
```

This solution makes loading a bit slower, but without browser hanging. Now I want to store this html with directives in service and load it when the route will be called again. But I encountered a problem, that if I load html+directives from service and bind it(with ng-bing-html) to the container I have to compile it again. Is there a way to store/cache and load html+ng without recompiling everything again? Or maybe faster and prettier method to implement directives to scope?